# Opencart Surepost: How to integrate surepost shipping rates?

Tags: opencart, ups

I've got a client that has an OpenCart site that requires the use of Surepost. He's got an account with Surepost that gives him special pricing. But the UPS module on OpenCart doesn;t support this, so UPS tech support said this:

"to use UPS Surepost special rates, you need to use the "Rate" option in the Request/RequestOption element. And you will no be able to use the "Shop" request option with the same request to compare rates for all other services. You will need to send a separate rate request to obtain non-SurePost rates."

One idea I've got is to copy the default UPS shipping extension and modify the xml. So then the site would have 2 UPS shipping extensions, one for regular rates and one for Surepost. Anyone have any ideas on how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi how were you able to solve this issue? We also have to add surepost on our opencart site but i am not sure how to. if you solved this issue, could you please post the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at a solution like [EasyPost](http://easypost.com) that supports Surepost - the native carrier integrations are a huge hassle.